# How to implement a snapchat like circular animated countdown timer component in React Native?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, snapchat

I was wondering if anyone knows how to implement a circular countdown timer in React Native shown on the attached image. Would be ideal if it was for both ios and android. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: requests for library recommendations are not welcome on SO. Please ready the FAQ for further details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can at least point you in the direction of implementing one yourself.

There does indeed exist a ['react-countdown-timer' component](https://github.com/buhe/react-native-countdown), however it might be worth implementing yourself or altering their code in order to make the timer appear like above. To do so, I would use a combination of timer-mixins in addition to a circular view with text inside.  Next, I would keep track of the state of the timer using the timer-mixins in addition to the setState function. For each interval, I would update the time remaining of the timer and then update the button component that you have created to reflect whatever time is left.

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement I would like to suggest you 
Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-av-countdown-circle this component